# How can I create an uninstall link in start menu for a ClickOnce application

Tags: c#, wpf, clickonce, uninstallation

Clickonce creates only a link in the start menu to run the application. I also want to create an uninstall link when a user installs my C# application using ClickOnce, preferably in the same submenu and next to the link for launching the application. 
(I am aware that it can be done with Add/remove programs, but it is a hassle to go there for every small application)

Background : I have created a series of [quantitative finance related calculators](http://www.quantcode.com/modules/mydownloads/) in my website, which are deployed using ClickOnce. The apps are for educational purpose, and user would want to remove it after a couple of days, or immediately if it was not what he was looking for. So I want to make uninstall easy

Answer (score 3):

ClickOnce won't add this shortcut for you.  ClickOnce will create a shortcut to launch your app and a shortcut to your help url, that's it.  If you want that shortcut created, you'll have to do it yourself in your app's code.

Basically, all you need to do is look in the registry at...
`HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\[Your app's key]\UninstallString`

Creating a shortcut out of that value (rundll32.exe dfshim.dll...) will accomplish what you want.  However, as PetPaulson pointed out in the comments, this shortcut won't be removed by the ClickOnce uninstall.  It will remain in their start menu; not good.

That said, I personally don't think it's worth the effort.  I really dislike apps that create all sorts of shortcuts (start menu, desktop, uninstall, etc) for me.  Most people know how to use Add/Remove Programs.  Just my personal preference, though.

Comment: Also note, that if you have created the uninstall shortcut by yourself, you will be responsible for removing it again upon uninstalling. Otherwise you will leave dead items in the menu bar. As whatknott said, not realy worth the effort.

Comment: Excellent point, forgot to mention that.  I'll make sure to edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft discourages this in its directives. Uninstallers should be accessible primarily from the "Add/Remove programs" dialog.